# Where can I find ImageLoader?

Tags: android

I'm trying to use [this](https://github.com/sephiroth74/ImageViewZoom) by sephiroth74, however, I'm having some troubles.

Here's my code so far: https://gist.github.com/3067961

I'm getting a red line under:

- loadFromUri (line 57): "The method loadFromUri(ImageZoomActivity, String, int, int) is undefined for the type ImageLoader"
- And, setImageBitmapReset (line 58): "The method setImageBitmapReset(Bitmap, int, boolean) is undefined for the type ImageViewTouch"

I wasn't exactly sure where to find the ImageLoader class, so I downloaded (http://code.google. com/p/libs-for-android/wiki/ImageLoader) one.. However, it's the wrong class, because those 2 methods evidently don't exist in it.

Can someone please help me find the correct class? I've looked everywhere I can!

Thanks

Comment: I'm confused - did you copy the ImageLoader code from somewhere?

Comment: I ended up deleting the class and not even using it. Thanks for the reply though!